# Why the women should be covered when praying?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, women, hijab, muslim-practices

As far as I know, the women should be covered (متحجبة) when praying, I understand that the women should be covered when meeting other people, but when she is "meeting" God, does that make sense? God can see everything, wherever, whenever.

Can someone explain the purpose of the women being covered when praying, given the fact that :

- she is alone in face of God
- God can see everything no matter what human being could do

Thanks

Comment: I'll add that it's not just women, but men also must be covered in the way prescribed for them (during salah and other times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Narrated from the Prophet determine clothes during the prayer  for men and women, not only for women
- That this covered is not for covered  person's (men \ women) awrah  outside of prayer only !!,

  **But because the right of prayer and it's worth not because they are  awrah ...**
- And for men they must also cover the shoulders during prayer, knowing that shoulders is not awrah for the men

> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَاصِمٍ، عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ أَبِي الزِّنَادِ، عَنْ
>   عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ
>   النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لاَ يُصَلِّي أَحَدُكُمْ فِي
>   الثَّوْبِ الْوَاحِدِ، لَيْسَ عَلَى عَاتِقَيْهِ شَىْءٌ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> The Prophet said, "None of you should offer prayer in a single garment
>   that does not cover the shoulders."
>
> [[Sahih al-Bukhari : 359]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/11)

- And I've mentioned that Ibn Omar, may Allah be pleased with him, he said to his servant, Nafi when he saw praying head Exposed:

> "What do you think if you went out to the people you go out like that?
>   Said: No, he said: God is more deserving of his beautifying"

Previous word to say in the novel Bayhaqi:

> "If one of you prayed should him dressed,So god more deserving of
>   adorning him"

Comment: so what about in hajj where men at least have one shoulder free in ihram?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt Allah is Aware of all things at all times and does not make sense for him hidden. No passers by its servants.But the human being to worship God sense and speaks with him, you should wear the best clothes in his presence.It is clear that the most suitable dresses for women is the sign of chastity and purity ,is her best clothes to reflect her moods. Such a suit is just worshiped,Even in the case of men, not only thats forbidden  with a bare body , u should dressed be a sign of respect to GOD.
mehraboon from iran